# Android queryInventoryAsync bug or not

Tags: android

I have been trying to implement google in app billing lately in an android application and today i witnessed something strange. I have an app witch sells non consumable products,more precisely a kind of information. Now the need is for having more than 150 products and when i query google for product info it seems that google does not respond to my request , i waited nearly 5 minutes and set a dialog which gets dismissed when google responds and populates an adapter which populates a spinner. Now i read somewhere that queryInventoryAsync can't deal with lists more than 20 items long,sorry about not having the link but I lost track of it searching all over google to find a solution or some explanation or a possible scenario to which i can refer. So my guesses are:

1. queryInventoryAsync cant handle 20+ items long lists
2. maybe it is the adapter that cant handle it
3. maybe the spinner would be better to be replaced by a ListView
4. or something else

I thank you in advance for any kind of effort. Good job stackoverflow comunity, thank you for being a place to exchange knowledge and share it. :)

So i hardcoded it and experienced it myself , i tried to send a query with a list with 20 elements and queryInventoryAsync responded, but with a list of more than 20 elements exh:23 it didn't. So now i am searching how to send subsequent requests to google while I split the list in parts if the original list has more than 20 elements. Help is needed , running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fell foul of this issue as well, or at least something very similar. The patch in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16833817/1537347) fixed the issue and allowed me to query more than 20 SKUs.

Also, if like me you are using the *.utils helpers from the Google Play Billing Library and installed the package from the Android SDK Manager, then you may fall foul of issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397343/google-play-in-app-billing-version-3-crash-on-item-already-owned-and-missing/). You should update the *.utils files from the [Google marketbilling repo](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/#git/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util), making sure you merge the changes from the answer above.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you man , helped me a lot. it was code invisible to me since I couldn't debug the Library since i was at my early android days and the code wasn't mine. Thank you